# Send parameters to Razor Page RCL NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, razor-class-library

Hello and thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

I'm working with .NET Core 3.1

I have a Razor Class Library with Razor Pages.

They are partial pages that are included inside views of a Web MVC project also .NET Core 3.1

The razor pages of the RCL are inside the "\Pages" folder in a "\Shares" subfolder.

I load the partial pages like this: `<partial name="_SpatialTest" />`

It works properly.

But I need to send several parameters to some of the Razor Pages of the RCL from the views that includes, and there comes my problem, since as it is not a hyperlink I cannot add the parameters in the routing, or in the Body, or in the querystring... as suggested here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

I have tried it as view-data, as model and data and it gives me several errors but it never works, like suggested here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

I've got it set up like this:

Razor Page in RCL ->

cshtml.cs:

```
namespace SpatialUnitsRclTest.Pages.Shared
{
    public class _SpatialTestModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string NameTest { get; set; }

        public void OnGet(send parameters)
        {
            // do something with the parameters and create the Razor Page ViewModel ...
        }
    }
}
```

cshtml:

```
@page
@model SpatialUnitsRclTest.Pages.Shared._SpatialTestModel
<h5>Test RCL partial @Model.NameTest</h5>
<div id="mapid" style="min-height: 180px;"></div>
```

View (cshtml) in Web MVC project ->

```
<div style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
    @{ var partialModel = new SpatialUnitsRclTest.Pages.Shared._SpatialTestModel { NameTest = "pruebaaaaaaaaaaa" }; }
    <partial name="_SpatialTest" model="@partialModel"  />
</div>
```

The error is:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. AspNetCore.Pages_Shared__SpatialTest.get_Model()
>   AspNetCore.Pages_Shared__SpatialTest.ExecuteAsync() in
>   _SpatialTest.cshtml
>   +     Test RCL partial @Model.NameTest Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
>   page, ViewContext context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
>   page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.RenderPartialViewAsync(TextWriter
>   writer, object model, IView view)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
>   context, TagHelperOutput output)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.g__Awaited|0_0(Task
>   task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
>   AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
>   +
>        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
>   page, ViewContext context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
>   page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
>   viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
>   viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
>   actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData,
>   ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable
>   statusCode)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
>   context, ViewResult result)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
>   Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
>   bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
>   isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
>   next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
>   endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Can you give me a hand?

Thanks a lot. Greetings.

Comment: No one has any idea why it fails? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to render partial view (contained in your RCL) with specified Model data within your MVC project view page, please refer to the following example.

*Razor View `_SpatialTest1` (in RCL)*

```
@model RclTest.Models.SpatialTestModel
@{
    //code logic here
}

<h1>_SpatialTest1</h1>
<h5>Test RCL partial @Model.NameTest</h5>
```

Note: create a ***Razor View*** `_SpatialTest1` in your RCL, not ***Razor Page***.

*SpatialTestModel class (in RCL)*

```
public class SpatialTestModel
{
    public string NameTest { get; set; }
}
```

*View page (in MVC project)*

```
@{
    var partialModel = new RclTest.Models.SpatialTestModel { NameTest = "pruebaaaaaaaaaaa" };
}

<partial name="_SpatialTest1" model="@partialModel" />
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

It could be an alternative, but the example I have given is very simple to explain my problem clearly (I am not able to pass parameters to the Razor Page of the RCL).

I am not really going to pass a name, but a configuration object with which in the "pseudo-controller" of RazorPage, in the OnGet method, I must perform actions, which will generate the model of the Razor Page.

Maybe I don't have a good idea of what I want to do?